# Determine constant in distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Some of the following random variables are described by the following common distribution function (common probability density function):

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}k(x^2+y^2) & 30\le x,y\le 50\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Considering interval $[30,50]$ and
$k(x^2+y^2)=0$

$k$ must be equal to $1$.

Is this correct approach?
Could you explain me what is the problem here and what I need to know to solve this? How do I determine constant k?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: I edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should integrate the density function:

$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dxdy = \int\limits_{30}^{50}\int\limits_{30}^{50}(kx^2 + ky^2)dxdy = \int\limits_{30}^{50}(\frac{k}{3}[x^3]_{30}^{50}+k[x]_{30}^{50}y^2)dy = \frac{k}{3}([x^3]_{30}^{50}[y]_{30}^{50}+[y^3]_{30}^{50}[x]_{30}^{50}) = \frac{2k}{3}(50^3-30^3)(50-30) = 1$

Therefore $k=\frac{3}{2*1960000}$

Comment: if interval was [10,20] or [30,40] would we still have to make equal result of integration and 1? Why is result of integration equal to 1? Could you explain me?

Comment: Because the probability density function is the probability that the random variable is in the interval [x ; x+dx]. Integrating over the entire space is the probability that the random variable is anywhere in that space, that is 1.
It is a condition for a density to be a density and it is a generalization of what you would expect of a probability in the discrete case (think about a die for example and what would be the sum of the probabilities that the die is 1, 2, ... up to 6).

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the notation $30\leq x,y \leq 50$ means this: $30\leq x \leq 50$ and $30\leq y \leq 50$.

The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)\, dxdy$$ must be equal to $1$, because it's a property of probability density function $f(x,y)$.

The meaning of this integral is probability that random vector (X,Y) will obtain a value $(x,y)$ from the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it's obvious that this probability must be $1$).

General formula for using probability density function $f(x,y)$ for calculating probability $P((X,Y) \in A)$, where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, is this:
$$P((X,Y) \in A) = \underset{A}{\iint} f(x,y)\, dxdy$$

Comment: thank you very much